# JavaFx 2.0 WebEngine component's Popup Handler not opening a new window for Skype button, also not connecting to skype for a phone call

Tags: javafx-2

I need to create a popup handler that opens an external window. How can I do this? The default opens the popup in the same webview, and there is no code in the JavaFx learning trail to provide me a general idea or anything. The origin of the popup request comes from a skype button widget. When the user clicks the widget a new "window" (stage) needs to open and the popup must be included within the new stage. The stage is just a composition of a Webview and its engine.

This should happen if the user does not have skype. If the user has skype then skype should open and connect the phone call. Neither is happening.

Update: I also asked in the JavaFx 2.0 forum and got an answer. Here it is. (I'll move it to the Answer area as soon as I can):

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2323123&tstart=0

It still wont open skype and connect for a phone call or open a popup to install skype.

Although the Javascript widget does open skype and connects for a phone call if I open the widget inside a browser in standalone mode.

Therefore it is an issue with the JavaFx 2.0 web app.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, to make calls from the browser Skype needs plugin named "Click to Call" to be installed into the browser.

But there is no such plugin for JavaFX WebView, so you can't have Skype "click-to-call" functionality inside webview.

Comment: Hey I need to ask you a question that may require a few lines, do you have time to chat?